# "|" as function argument? (Java)

Tags: java, parameters, arguments

I just read code where someone passed to a function of this look:

> void function(String a, int b)

these arguments: function("abc", x|y);

x and y were defined earlier as integers. I tried to look this up but can't find any article.
Can someone explain me the use and meaning of this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`|` operator performs a bitwise inclusive OR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: That would be bitwise OR.

Comment: That's a bitwise operator.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. Haven't seen this before in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bitwise OR.

Let's say `a=5`and `b=3`, `a|b==7`

Refer to [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for java Bitwise operator.

And [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) for a complete explanation about binary operation: